# How is the "command line" passed from the bootloader (grub) to the kernel (linux)?

Tags: boot, boot-loader

Grub (or other) sends command line arguments to the linux kernel, to modify certain parameters.

If I wanted to go in and see this information, before the kernel is up (and potentially modify it), where would one look? Is this stored at a specific place in memory that the kernel knows to look for?

I understand it's placed under a /proc entry once the kernel is up, but I'm looking for pre-OS information on how this works (maybe this is the wrong place?)

This is a question about the method of which a bootloader passes information to the next elf in the sequence (generally, but not exclusively, a kernel). This has nothing to do with grub settings

Comment: I don't think so, I'm asking more of a theoretical question, and grub is in fact just an example. I'm looking for the method which a bootloader passes information to the kernel (or whatever elf is loaded next in the process)

Comment: I just want to add (besides answering) that your Q really touches a basic concept, and the Q reveals some misunderstanding. I know the A is accepted, no problem, the link is very correct. I'm just signalling -- got caught here by commenting s.k. (see acc. answer)

Comment: I see now: two very good links by stephen. But when I ask about initial ramdisk he shrugs his shoulder. See comments. That is why I had to post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grub implements [the multiboot specification](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot2/multiboot.html). When it loads the kernel and hands over control to it, it passes a pointer to [an information structure](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot2/multiboot.html#Boot-information-format) in memory. One of the fields in that structure is the command line.

The Linux kernel has its own [boot protocol](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/boot.html), but [the command line](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/boot.html#the-kernel-command-line) is handled in a similar fashion: the boot loader leaves it in memory, and fills in various fields in a kernel data structure which allow the kernel to find it.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! Seems a little sketchy that it's passed in a register, but I guess that's the only way

Comment: Is this useful to you. I was expecting you to want to know where on disk it is stored.

Comment: "This [module] tag indicates to the kernel what boot module was loaded along with the kernel image." What kind of **modules** does grub here indicate to the kernel?

Comment: @rastafile those are [multiboot modules](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot2/multiboot.html#Boot-modules). AFAIK they aren’t used when booting Linux.

Comment: from the "2 Definitions" part it must be the initrd "module", in (multiboot-) boot loader speech, which is meant. All the other parts are mentioned (kernel, bootloader,...where is initrd?)

Comment: @rastafile initrd is a Linux concept, not a multiboot concept. I suspect that yes, in a multiboot scenario the initramfs would be a boot module, but I haven’t verified that. Multiboot modules are used for other kernels, not the Linux kernel (usually).

Comment: There is a large hole in your concept. I know from a former life. (former VL). Now it come back, the hole. Please verify.

Comment: @rastafile what hole? What do you mean by “VL”?

Comment: I posted an answer, 95% citing and bolding the multiboot link (contents thereof). Please have a look. I was quite surprised too how easy it was to show what I mean. VL is Virtual Life. I think it shows in SE, indirectly. It is an interface thing.

Comment: Because, some things really are between our faces --- not personally, I mean technically, our terminals, the net, the "avatars". You are a human, I know that (turing test?). But I know not much more - it is a fake world.

Answer (score 0):

After the bootloader does it's bootloading housekeeping, it starts a minimal OS environment, usually based on the initrd.img or initramfs. The kernel parameters you see in a grub file are directed to the kernel that boots up after this minimal environment. Usually for all intents and purposes when you execute mkinitrd, sane settings chosen from /etc are used to configure this initrd image.

By the time the usual bootup sequence happens, the initial environment has been pivoted away and the usual kernel is used. One thing to note, drivers that are started in the initrd can stay resident into normal execution, which can be a source of great head scratching.

Comment: I figured there was a step between bootloader and kernel. That's useful information, but I'm not sure it answers the question. '... are directed to the kernel...' I'm still looking for how this part is done. Is it just placed in the stack like the argv of a c program?

Comment: isn't that just a jump to an address and uncompress/load everything in the initrd? There's probably a bunch of calls to initialise the cpu as well

Comment: Then where is the "cmdline" information stored? Is it in the fdt, or is it in a specific place in memory that the kernel knows to look for it? This information is somehow passed from bootloader to the second executable (mini kernel in this example) in the chain.

Comment: Maybe it's in this: https://github.com/coreos/grub/blob/2.02-coreos/grub-core/boot/i386/pc/boot.S

Comment: Hi placid.  All you say is 100% correct. Only: What Q are you answering? Or rather: what is the title of your statements? Pl. check out my contributions all over the place in this Q. How can this be put in structured plain english?

Comment: housekeeping? (but I kept on reading -- terrible start, very good article ;)